# probability of a certain event in a repeated sampling with replacement (without ordering)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, sampling, law-of-large-numbers

I have a problem that is bugging me for a couple of weeks now. I have asked some friends etc but the answers were not satisfying at all.
So here we go.

Suppose we have a set `S = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` and each time we pick a random number from this set. After $N$ pickups suppose that the number, `lets say 6`, has never been picked. 
The question is, what is the probability of picking number 6 in the $N + 1$ pickup knowing that it has not been picked for the previous $N$ pickups?

I know that people will rush and say, its just $\frac 1 {10}$ but if we consider the previous pickups, meaning that we have a "memory" in the "system" doesn't it change everything?

Imagine a representation of the distribution of # of picks on X axis and # of actually possible values to be picked in Y axis. [Law of Large Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) says that approximately every possible value will have the same number of pickups after a very large number of repetitive samplings N. Supposing that we have rolled for a large number of, lets say dice, and we see that a specific number has not been rolled yet, lets say the 6. Doesn't this implies that it is almost certain that the roll 6 has to come, it was just too unlikely to not have been rolled up to now, given that the dice is "fair"?

I tried to solve this as binomial with Conditional Probability but i think its wrong cause the set is dynamic while Conditional Probability needs a constant set.
My wrong answer is here:

$N$ is known

Number $k$ $\in$ $S$ has $P_k$ = $\frac 1 {10}$ and $Q_k$ = $\frac 9 {10}$

In $N$ pickups no success:  $A$

In $N + 1$ pickups $1$ success: $B$

Binomial:

$p ( X=0)=$ $\binom{N}{0} P^0 Q^N =(\frac {9} {10})^N$

$p ( X=1)=$ $\binom{N+1}{1} P^1 Q^{N} ={\frac {(N+1)!} {N!}} (\frac {1} {10})(\frac {9} {10})^{N}=(N+1)(\frac {1} {10})(\frac {9} {10})^{N}$

And so we ask for the probability of B, given that A has been fulfilled:

$p(B/A) = \frac {P(B\bigcap A)} {P(A)} = \frac {\frac {1} {10}} {(\frac {9}{10})^N} =(\frac {10}{9})^N (\frac {1}{9})$

This seems to be wrong since $p > 1$ for large N.

Thanks in advance and sorry if i did not make the question clear enough. I do not know well the mathematics' definitions in English.

***EDIT***: I have corrected $P(B\bigcap A)$ and $p ( X=1)$.

Comment: I suppose you could try to gamble this way, but it won't work. Consider flipping coins. Do you really think if you got three heads in a row that it would make tails more likely on the next flip? If so, Las Vegas would have a problem - bettors at roulette could wait until "red" came up four times in a row, and then bet bigger on black. Luckily for Las Vegas, this is not the way random events work - there is no "memory" in a system like this.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are right but dont forget that probability is not affected much in Las vegas cause it would take hundrends of repetitive reds just to slightly (i guess still insignificant) improve the probability that the next one will be black.

Comment: Well, you say lots of reds in a row slightly improves the odds of black, but you haven't actually shown it, you've just asserted it. Definitely worth running your own experiments with coin tosses to see how it works...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are right and I guess thats what I am trying to understand. I think the problem here is from what perspective we see the problem. If you only see the standar set of 10 elements its 1/10. What if you want to see a dynamic set that increases and considers the values that have already been picked? This changes everything.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, and see if it makes things any clearer for you. Let me know if there's anything you're still unsure about.

Comment: You are simply asserting it is a dynamic system with memory. There is no evidence of this, and *lots* of real-world and mathematical reasons to believe that it has no memory. Does the coin have memory? What if you flipped a single coin $5$ times and it came up heads each time. Then you flipped a new coin. Would it be likelier to be tails? How would that mechanism even work?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are right and thats where i get on a brick wall and my questions start. We know that having 5 times heads in a row is like (1/2)^5. We also know that the further u get it the more likely it is to change. for example (1/2)^10000 is very unlikely to happen and it implies that we should probably have already get a tails somewhere. How can we ignore this? We dont cause we know that for a large number of flips we would have an even number for heads and tails (approximately).

Comment: If your assertion is right, $5$ heads in a row is *not* $\frac{1}{2^5}$ since four heads in a row makes it less likely that the fifth is heads. The reason it is unlikely to be $10000$ in a wow is all those cumulative $1/2$s which don't change, not because the odds of tails becomes greater over time. If you get $10000$ heads in a row, the odds the next will be tails is still $1/2$. (Well, assuming you have a fair coin - $10000$ heads in a row might discourage that belief.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews For the shake of arguments, lets not pick a coin cause its not clear enough. Lets take a dice. If you see it from a complementary probability you can see that the chance of `NOT` getting in 5 rolls a 6 is $1- \frac{1}{6^5}$ and it continues to increase as you continue to roll and not getting a 6. This tends to become a 1 for a large number of rolls without getting a 6. What does this say to us? That its impossible to not roll a six after, lets say, $100000$ rolls though it doesnt specify the exact roll but the general sum or rolls.

Comment: Why is a coin not "clear enough." The odds for dice are exactly the same, the coin is *simpler* so it has more clarity.

Comment: The theorem that you allude to is called [The Law of Large Numbers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) To be precise, there are several theorems with similar names. I hope you will find the Wikipedia article informative,

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for the information. May I ask you, is it correct that I have applied Conditional Probability as shown in my question? I mean, I usually applied it in the same sets that were created by the events. This somehow feels wrong here. Thanks again.

Comment: On the line before "this seems to be wrong" you use the very wrong $P(B\cap A)=\frac{1}{10}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of choosing $6$ at any given time is *independent* of whether it has been chosen before, which is why the answer is simply $\frac1{10}.$

You can still calculate it as a conditional probability, of course, but you've miscalculated your $P(B\cap A),$ which is why you get a "probability" greater than $1$ eventually. Note that $B\cap A$ is the event in which $6$ is *not* chosen in the first $N$ picks, but *is* chosen once in $N+1$ picks (so necessarily on pick $N+1$). Equivalently, $B\cap A$ is the event of choosing $6$ for the first time on pick $N+1$. Part of the issue is that your $A$ and $B$ are **not** independent, so that makes calculation more cumbersome. Instead, let $C$ be the event of choosing $6$ on pick $N+1,$ and note that $C\cap A=B\cap A,$ and that the events $A,C$ ("never having chosen $6$ before" and "choosing $6$ now") *are* independent. Thus, $$p(B\cap A)=p(C\cap A)=p(C)p(A)=\frac1{10}\cdot\left(\frac9{10}\right)^N.$$ Put another way:

- In $\left(\frac9{10}\right)^N$ of our possible outcomes, we have not chosen $6$ in the first $N$ picks.
- In $\frac1{10}$ of **those** outcomes, we'll choose $6$ at pick $N+1$--specifically, when we choose $6$ next, rather than some other number.
- $\frac1{10}$ of $\left(\frac9{10}\right)^N$ is $\frac1{10}\cdot\left(\frac9{10}\right)^N,$ the fraction of our possible outcomes in which we choose $6$ for the first time at pick $N+1$.

Thus, the probability is $$p(B\mid A)=\frac{p(B\cap A)}{p(A)}=\cfrac{\frac1{10}\cdot\left(\frac9{10}\right)^N}{\left(\frac9{10}\right)^N}=\frac1{10}.$$

---

Suppose we approach it combinatorically, instead?

There are $10^{N+1}$ total ways to make a sequence of $N+1$ picks from $S,$ ***but*** we already know that $6$ was not chosen in the first $N$ picks, so our sample space is narrowed (perhaps substantially, depending on how large $N$ is).

There are $9^N$ possible ways to make a sequence of $N$ choices from $S$ **without** choosing $6$. From this, it follows that:

- There are $9^N\cdot 10$ possible ways to make a sequence of $N+1$ choices from $S$ without choosing $6$ **except possibly** at pick $N+1$. (This is the cardinality of our "narrowed" sample space.)
- There are $9^N$ possible ways to make a sequence of $N+1$ choices from $S$ where $6$ is chosen for the **first time** at pick $N+1$. (This is the cardinality of the event we're interested in.)

Hence, the probability that we choose a $6$ on pick $N+1$, *given that* we haven't chosen $6$ in any of the previous $N$ picks, is $$\frac{9^N}{9^N\cdot 10}=\frac1{10}.$$

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. The whole idea was based on that theorem that I cannot recall about the equal distribution of all elements of a set after a large number of repetitive pickups. 1/10 is correct but only if you dont care about repetitive pickups. Suppose that you have seen a sampling that for 10000000 pickups number 6 has not been picked. Ofcourse this is very unlikely to happen `but` how can you prove that it doesnt affect the next pickup when you see a hole in the distribution table of that value (6) along all the others?

Comment: Also my answer is still wrong even with 1/10 as you said cause p still gets greater than 1 for large N.

Comment: Well, your latter objection is easier to answer. The probability will *not*, in fact, be greater than $1$, as $$p(B\mid A)=\frac{p(B\cap A)}{p(A)}=\cfrac{\frac1{10}\cdot \left(\frac9{10}\right)^N}{\left(\frac9{10}\right)^N}=\frac1{10}.$$ As for the former objection, let me add another approach to my answer.

Comment: I've added a combinatoric approach. Do each of those steps make sense to you? If not, let me know which confuse(s) you, and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: How did you calculate  $P(B\bigcap A)$ ?? Can you see again what I have set as A and B and verify it again plz? If A and B are independent with each other its just a multiplication of $P(A)P(B)$ right? Thanks

Comment: I cannot understand which is the correct $P(B\bigcap A)$. If A,B independent from each other, shouldnt we just multiply $p ( X=1)$ and $p ( X=0)$ ? Or, $\frac 1 {10}$ should be the $A\bigcap B$?

Comment: Your $A,B$ are actually *not* independent from each other, since if $A$ fails, then $B$ is very likely to have failed already, regardless of what happens in pick $N+1$. I've explained my calculation of $p(B\cap A)$ further. Have you taken a look at the combinatoric approach, yet?

Comment: Does my explanation make more sense to you, now? Do you still have questions?

Comment: one question: Is it correct to apply Conditional Probability in sequential sampling? Meaning that, when we use conditional probability we just change the set according to what we need. In a 2-dices example we can apply it like: Given that we have rolled a $10$, whats the probability that the dices rolled a 5 (each one and not,lets say, 6 and 4). I am feeling that the whole approach is incorrect like i have aforementioned in the original post. I know that I sound weird for not been convinced so far.

Comment: It's absolutely fine (though unnecessary) to use conditional probability. (There is never a time when we can't use it, somehow, but often, it's overly cumbersome, and there are better ways.) The only thing that was incorrect, here, was your calculation of $p(B\cap A).$